# React native setState didn't work in useEffect

Tags: react-native, state, use-effect, use-state, setstate

I expect it show **Array[1,2,3]** in termeral,but it's not.Can someone help me figure out!

```
const [data,setData]=useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
  setData([1,2,3]);
  console.log(data);//show Array[] 
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

First you wanna make sure you are purposefully omitting your dependencies array in `useEffect`. Currently you are letting react auto generate your dependency array, which I believe would be `[data, setData]`. Anytime these values changed your effect would be called, meaning that if the value of data is changed your effect is called and data would become `[1,2,3]` again.

If your desired result is to call this effect at first render pass an empty dependency array to the effect:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  setData([1,2,3]); 
},[])
```

If you want to log data whenever it changes `useEffect` with data as its dependency

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('data has been updated!');
  console.log(data);
},[data])
```